# incrementing int variable in for loop java

Tags: java

Guys I am trying to understand why we have incremented frequency and divided grade by 10 could somebody please help explain.

```
public void getBarChart(){

    System.out.println("\nGrade Distribution: ");

    int[] frequency = new int[11];

    for (int grade : grades)
        ++frequency[grade / 10];

    for (int counter =0 ; counter < frequency.length; counter++){


        if(counter == 10){

            System.out.printf("%5d:  ",100);
        }

        else{

            System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: "
                    ,counter * 10, counter * 10 + 9 );
        }

        for (int stars= 0; stars < frequency[counter] ; stars++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: so what line(what exactly do you don't understand)?

Comment: It is storing the amount of grades that it finds in a certain range.  Imagine the value of grade is 78, then it will increment to number in the seventh element of the frequency array

Comment: @inoxy probably the line where he _"...  incremented frequency and divided grade by 10 ..."_ like it says in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `grade` can be between 0 and 100, the `frequency` array counts how many grades fall in the groups 0-9, 10-19, ..., 90-99, 100.

That's the reason you divide `grade` by 10 to locate the array index.

`++frequency[grade / 10]` increments the count of grades that fall in the group of that grade.

So, for example, the grade 75 will be counted in the array element `frequency[75 / 10]` which is `frequency[7]`. `frequency[7]` will contain the number of grades in the range 70 to 79.